# Asp.Net MVC Finding the previous page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have GenericPagecontroller in my project which renders GenericPage.aspx. There are links in the homepage and in two other pages for this GenericPageconroller.Now based on from where it is invoked, i have diiferent data to pass in to the GenericPage.aspx. ie If the Controller is requested from HomePage i have different set of data to show in the view and if it from other page i need to display  diiferent set of data in the view. As of now i have kept an optional parameter in the Index method (the default method in GenericController) and added a querystring in the URL which holds the current page's name. Thus from the paramter i find from which link the request comes and load the appropriate data into the view.

Is there any way to achieve this instead having a querystring which carries the related information...? some way to dynamically to find this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check `Request.UrlReferrer` which contains the referring page.

This method is not 100% reliable however.

Comment: Paul@: yes, i guess i am left with no other option since i have a main page and all other other pages will be jquery tabs inside the main page,so from where ever i click i get the Mainpage's URL which is obvious..

Comment: @Dainel, I don't think you should use the querystring though, use a parameter and a route!

Comment: One more problem is the modules are separated into Areas

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use TempData for storing the url before redirecting, however System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer should help you

Comment: I would suggest to add more explanation. What it does? Why? How?